# Auto-correlation of time signals

Tags: autocorrelation, time-series

I'm interested in papers which are about auto-correlations of periodic **time series** signals.All relevant papers and applications are interesting to me, as I am studying the properties of the auto-correlation of periodic, digital time signals.

The reason, I am asking you for this help,is that due to my own search, I am well aware of the magnitude of work on the analysis of spectral properties of cyclostationary time series and this makes it difficult for me to locate the important scientists that introduced and pushed the analysis of periodic/cyclostationry features of time series. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @Marcel, your question is vague however, I will try to provide you some link which may give some directions on cyclostationarity: https://sites.google.com/site/antnapol/home/tutorials . I suggest you to be more specific in asking questions here.